# Olympiad problem about finding minimum value with $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2\ge x^2y^2z^2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers such that $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2\ge x^2y^2z^2$.

Find the minimum value of
$$\frac{x^2y^2} {z^3(x^2+y^2)}+\frac {y^2z^2} {x^3(y^2+z^2)}+\frac {z^2x^2} {y^3(z^2+x^2)}$$
I'm pretty sure that the answer would be $\frac {\sqrt {3}} {2}$, when all parameters are $\sqrt {3}$. But I couldn't prove it after some hours of thinking. So can anyone help me?
Any help would be welcome.
Thanks:D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$a=\dfrac{1}{x},b=\dfrac{1}{y},c=\dfrac{1}{z},a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 1$$
Use Cauchy-Schwarz 
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{x^2y^2}{z^3(x^2+y^2)}=\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{c^3}{(a^2+b^2)}\ge \dfrac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{c(a^2+b^2)+a(b^2+c^2)+b(c^2+a^2)}$$
since
$$c(a^2+b^2)+a(b^2+c^2)+b(c^2+a^2)\le\dfrac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\le\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
so
$$LHS\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz refers to the fact that the square of the sum of products is smaller than the product of the sums of squares. Could you please elaborate more on how you obtained the second row ?

Comment: math110 thank you very much:). The second row is from Chebychev and QM-AM inequality Lucian.

Comment: yes, that's  your mean.@Riverboat

Answer (score 0):

If $x=y=z=\sqrt3$ then we get a value $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value, for which it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2z^2}{x^3(y^2+z^2)}\geq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2}{x^2y^2z^2}}$$ or

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^3z^3}{x^2(y^2+z^2)}\geq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\sqrt{x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2}.$$
Let $xy=c$, $xz=b$ and $yz=a$ and since our inequality is homogeneous,

we can assume that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{3-a^2}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or 
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^3}{3-a^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)(2a^2+3a+3)}{3-a^2}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(a-1)(2a^2+3a+3)}{3-a^2}-2(a^2-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2(2a^2+6a+3)}{3-a^2}\geq0.$$
Done!